# Why recover() does not work in a nested deferred function?

Tags: go, error-handling

I am testing `panic/recover` in Golang. This simple program works as expected:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func printRecover() {
    r := recover()
    fmt.Println("Recovered:", r)
}

func main() {
    defer printRecover()

    panic("OMG!")
}
```

Output:

```
Recovered: OMG!
```

However, if I wrap the function `printRecover()` in a bigger deferred function:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func printRecover() {
    r := recover()
    fmt.Println("Recovered:", r)
}

func main() {
    defer func() {
        printRecover()
    }()

    panic("OMG!")
}
```

It does not recover and let the panic go through:

```
Recovered: <nil>
panic: OMG!

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox898315096/main.go:15 +0x60
```

Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: In addition to the answer with a link to the spec; the [`recover` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#recover) also says "Executing a call to recover inside a deferred function (but not any function called by it) …"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is because `recover` will be `nil` if not directly called by deferred function

Here is excerpt from golang spec

> The return value of recover is nil if any of the following conditions holds:
>
> 1. panic's argument was nil;
> 2. the goroutine is not panicking;
> 3. **recover was not called directly by a deferred function.**

For more info check the full spec [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics)

Comment: why is that? why a function called by a deferred function cannot perceive the panic?